# Weighted mean with by function

Tags: r

Trying to get weighted mean for a couple of categories want to use by(df$A,df$B,function(x) weighted.mean(x,df$C)) This doesn't work of course. Is there a way to do this using by() and weighted.mean()

```
 df= data.frame(A=c(1,4,56,4,3),B=c('hi','gb','hi','gb','yo'),C=c(5,2,4,1,3))

 by(df$A,df$B,function(x) weighted.mean(x,df$C)) #doesn't work
```

I have a bunch of work arounds but it would so simple if I could just use that format.

Comment: Why should it? `by` applies functions to subsets of a dataset, and you're trying to pass a weight vector that's the length of the original dataframe's number of observations.

Comment: Why must you use `by`? This is easy with package plyr (or data.table or dplyr): `library(plyr); ddply(df, .(B), summarise, wm = weighted.mean(A, C))`

Comment: Another option is `lapply(split(df, df$B), function(x) weighted.mean(x$A, x$C))` since it seems you don't mind a list as output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the weights along with the values to be averaged in `by()`:

```
by(df[c("A","C")], df$B, function(x) weighted.mean(x$A, x$C))
# df$B: gb
# [1] 4
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# df$B: hi
# [1] 25.44444
# ------------------------------------------------------------ 
# df$B: yo
# [1] 3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was after. I also wanted to use [] to specify column numbers. `by(df[,c(1,3)], df[,2], function(x) weighted.mean(x[,1], x[,3]))` In my real dataframe the original columns were in the 30's and but in the weighted.mean part they were 1,2. like `by(charlie[c(9,33,35)], charlie[,4], function(x) weighted.mean(x[,3]/x[,2], x[,1], na.rm = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple and efficient solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(WM = weighted.mean(A, C)), B]
#     B       WM
# 1: hi 25.44444
# 2: gb  4.00000
# 3: yo  3.00000
```

Or using `split` and `apply` combination from base R

```
sapply(split(df, df$B), function(x) weighted.mean(x$A, x$C))
#      gb       hi       yo 
# 4.00000 25.44444  3.00000
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(B) %>%
  summarise(WM = weighted.mean(A, C))
# Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
# 
# B       WM
# 1 gb  4.00000
# 2 hi 25.44444
# 3 yo  3.00000
```

Comment: Thanks for all the options. I thought I had tried the split option but didn't work...Works.

Comment: In general, I would avoid using `by` for two reasons: It is VERY slow, second reason is- that you can't use its output as it and you need to find a way to convert it back to a data frame.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was writing it to a text file and the layout of `by` looks better in that case. Is `sapply(split()` much faster?

Comment: Don't know, you will have to benchmark I guess if it is really important to you.

Comment: I posted a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71183209

Answer (score 3):

Or simply recreate the calculation used by `weighted.mean()`:

```
by(df,df$B,function(df)with(df,sum(A*C)/sum(C)))

df$B: gb
[1] 4
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$B: hi
[1] 25.44444
------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$B: yo
[1] 3
```